# How can I make the raycast hit to hit only with the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a circle with line renderer and in the Update I want that if the Player touch the drawn part of the circle to detect it hit it. The problem is no matter if the Player is on the circle or not it always detect the terrain.

This script is attached to empty GameObject.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject centerObject;
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5)] public float width = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 100)] public float height = 0;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;

    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 endPos;
    private bool detected = false;

    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        

        if (draw)
            CreatePoints();

        startPos = line.GetPosition(0);
        endPos = line.GetPosition(line.positionCount - 1);

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(startPos, endPos - startPos, out hit))
        {
            if(hit.transform.gameObject.name == "Player")
            {
                print("player detected");
                detected = true;
            }
            else if(detected)
            {
                print("player NOT detected");
                detected = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        float x;
        float y;

        var angle = 20f;
        var points = new Vector3[segments + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

            points[i] = new Vector3(x, height, y);

            angle += (380f / segments);
        }

        // it's way more efficient to do this in one go!
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;
    private float prevHeight;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // Can't set up our line if the user hasn't connected it yet.
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;

        if (!draw)
        {
            // instead simply disable the component
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise re-enable the component
            // This will simply re-use the previously created points
            line.enabled = true;

            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth || height != prevHeight)
            {
                CreatePoints();

                // Cache our most recently used values.
                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
                prevHeight = height;
            }

            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

The Player have a Rigidbody 3d component, Capsule Collider , Third Person User Control, and Third Person Character. I'm using the keys WSAD to move the player.

I tried to use Physics.CheckSphere but it show "Player Detected" also if the player is inside the radius area and I want it to detect the player only on the drawn line of the circle.

This screen shot show the player touch the circle line :
This is what I mean to touch the drawn line of the circle :

[image: Player touch the circle]

And this is when the player is moved inside the circle and it also write player detected but it should write not detected that's what I want that only if he touch the line detect the player.

[image: Player is inside the circle area should not be detected only when touching the circle line.]

This is what I changed in the script :
I add a targetLayers variable and then in the Update using the Physics.CheckSphere.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject centerObject;
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5)] public float width = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 100)] public float height = 0;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask targetLayers;

    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 endPos;

    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (draw)
            CreatePoints();

        startPos = line.GetPosition(0);
        endPos = line.GetPosition(line.positionCount - 1);

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, xRadius, targetLayers))
        {
            Debug.Log("player detected");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("player NOT detected");
        }
    }

    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        float x;
        float y;

        var angle = 20f;
        var points = new Vector3[segments + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

            points[i] = new Vector3(x, height, y);

            angle += (380f / segments);
        }

        // it's way more efficient to do this in one go!
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;
    private float prevHeight;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // Can't set up our line if the user hasn't connected it yet.
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;

        if (!draw)
        {
            // instead simply disable the component
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise re-enable the component
            // This will simply re-use the previously created points
            line.enabled = true;

            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth || height != prevHeight)
            {
                CreatePoints();

                // Cache our most recently used values.
                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
                prevHeight = height;
            }

            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Use [layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html)! See the 4th parameter of [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)! Also .. currently you are only raycasting between the start and end point of the circle .. you never update these points .. is this your intention? Why not rather use e.g. [`Physics.CheckSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html) again with according LayerMask

Comment: @derHugo I tried to use the Physics.CheckSphere but it's detecting the player also if the player is inside the circle radius area and I want it to detect the player only if the player touch the line.  Updated my question with two screenshots and the changes I did.

Answer (score 1):

Your raycast can hit only with determined [layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html).
For example:

```
int layerMask1 = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("EnemiesLayer");
int layerMask2 = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("GroundLayer");
int layerMask3 = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("PlayerPlayer");
int myLayerMask= layerMask1 | layerMask1 | layerMask3;
```

Then use this raycast overload, with the layer as an argument so that you can retrieve the first hit with any of the layers involved.

```
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance, int layerMask);
```

You just need to use this approach setting a layer for your player and defining the corresponding layer for the raycast.

Comment: Then rather use a [`[SerializeField] private LayerMask targetLayers;`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) and configure them in the Inspector (more secure than using strings ;) ) and as parameter you use [`targetLayers.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask-value.html)

Comment: sure, much better if hardcoding is avoided ;)

Answer (score 0):

As said before Use [layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html)! See the 4th parameter of [Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)!

Also .. currently you are only raycasting between the start and end point of the circle .. you never update these points so you will be casting the ray in a straight line .. doesn't sound like what you are trying to achieve.

---

After your update

You are using a `LineRenderer` so you could try from [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-add-collider-to-a-line-renderer.505307)

- Use a `MeshCollider` component
- Use [`LineRenderer.BakeMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.BakeMesh.html?_ga=2.14622768.608854487.1609596337-1503811403.1600323997) to create a mesh from the current line and use it as the mesh for the collider

Something like

```
var lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
var meshCollider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();

var mesh = new Mesh();
lineRenderer.BakeMesh(mesh, true);
meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;
```

Then you can use the usual [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) stuff and wouldn't even need to use a raycast.